# Android compress bitmap failed with write failed: EBADF (Bad file descriptor)

Tags: android, linux, io

Sometimes (and right now I am struggling to figure out the pattern), my `bitmap.compress` fails with the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: write failed: EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
   at libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:498)
   at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:186)
   at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCompress(Native Method)
   at android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(Bitmap.java:1027) 
   <...>
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: write failed: EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
   at libcore.io.Posix.writeBytes(Native Method)
   at libcore.io.Posix.write(Posix.java:271)
   at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.write(BlockGuardOs.java:313)
   at libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:493)
   ... 11 more
   : ------- write threw an exception
```

The code looks fairly standard:

```
FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = getMediaFileDescriptor(thumbUri);
OutputStream outputStream = null;
if (fileDescriptor != null) {
    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileDescriptor);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, outputStream);
}
```

`getMediaFileDescriptor()` does this:

```
 private FileDescriptor getMediaFileDescriptor(Uri uri) {
    try {
        ParcelFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = mContext.getContentResolver()
                .openFileDescriptor(uri, "w");
        return (fileDescriptor != null) ? fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor() : null;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        <...>
    }
    return null;
}
```

Is there any good fix for this and why does it happen? Also what is a 'bad' file descriptor?

Comment: What exactly is `outputUri`? Do you hold the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission? What is your `targetSdkVersion`?

Comment: `outputUri` is a param given to `getMediaFileDescriptor()` - I got a bit too eager removing the unnecessary stuff and it looks confusing now. Will update in a second and call it just `uri`. Yes I do have the permission and the code works most of the time. Target sdk is 23

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are fussing with all this `FileDescriptor` stuff and are not just calling `mContext.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri)`?

Comment: hmm, good question.. I used to have but I don't anymore. Thanks!!

Comment: ah, actually I do unfortunately.. I use my own file descriptor for managing the files and things like delete require I register my uri with the file descriptor

Comment: "I use my own file descriptor for managing the files and things like delete" -- a `Uri` does not have to be backed by a file that you can delete.

Comment: sure, but when I delete the file it's easier to delete from file descriptor which will delete the file from the disk. that's the pattern I use for the rest of the files generated by my app, so it would be great to stick with that pattern.